# Custom View into a Toast - doesn't draw

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, toast, custom-view

i'm trying to show a Toast message with a custom view i created.
the view has a bitmap on the background and i want to write some text on it.

if I assign the bitmap to an ImageView on the main code I manage to make it show up with Toast t; (...) t.show();
but when it's the onDraw() method of my class to assign the bitmap nothing shows up.
i checked, and my view has a size of (0, 0) when created the way i transcribe under.

help please.

**Main.java**

```
    Toast t = new Toast(this);
    LimitView lv = new LimitView(this);

    t.setView(lv);
    t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
```

**LimitView.java**

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.limit));

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: "but when it's the onDraw() method of my class to assign the bitmap nothing shows up". This part is not clear to me.

Comment: @Raghunandan: meaning it doesn't work as it is shown

Comment: you don't see the image

Comment: i already managed @Raghunandan. check Ȃŵåiṩ ĸîŋg solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

**Main.java**

`Context context = this;`

```
Toast t = new Toast(context);
LeftBorder lv = new LimitView(context);
t.setView(lv);
t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

**LimitView.java**

```
public class LimitView extends View {
    public LimitView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button_pressed), getMatrix(), new Paint());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference? and what is wrong with the code posted

Comment: **setBitmap** is used to draw mutable bitmap in canvas.

Comment: @Ȃŵåiṩĸîŋg i was asking why it won't work. 

Babibu post cleared my doubt

Comment: ok :)
btw if you should select any one of answers as right answer.

Comment: ok... working.
as i'm using API7 getMatrix() is not available
used drawBitmap(bmp, 0.0f, 0.0f, new Paint())

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors here.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.limit)
```

This is a heavy operation and should not be on view drawing phase.

```
canvas.setBitmap();
```

This method does not drawing bitmap on canvas but setting the canvas buffer to use this bitmap.

Try some thing like this:

```
public class MyView extends View{

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.limit);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace this 

canvas.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.limit));
```

to this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button_pressed),left,top, new Paint());
```

here left and right are the position of the screen.